# Gerar apenas um cabeçalho em Tabela com PHP usando Foreach

Tags: php, html5

estou trabalhando em uma aplicação simples que faz a leitura de arquivos XML, pego os dados faço o processamento e depois mostro na tela os dados que quero dos XML, toda via estou mostrando em uma tabela e o cabeçalho está se repentindo devido está dentro do foreache, se eu tirar a tabela do foreach não mostra os dados, alguém sabe como mostrar apenas o cabecalho e apenas os dados se repetirem ?

Vou deixar a imagem de como a tabela e mostrada e uma parte do codigo

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );

//Instanciando o OBJ
$xml = new DOMdocument();

//Pegando o TMP do FORM
$arquivo = $_FILES['entXML']['tmp_name'];

    //Total de todos os XML
      $totArquivos = 0;

      $arquivos = $arquivo;

//Navegando no Nodes(Nós)
foreach( $arquivos as$arquivos){

 //Carregando o XML
 $xml ->load($arquivos) or die(" ");
  //Entra dentro do NÓ pai do XML
  $arquivos = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );

    //Pega Nome
      $nomes = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "xNome" );
      $nome = $nomes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    //Pega CNPJ
      $cnpjS = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "CNPJ" );
      $cnpj = $cnpjS->item(0)->nodeValue;

    //Mostra dados do Emitente
      echo"<header class='text-center'>";
          echo"<div class='col-sm-6 Dempresa'><b>Empresa(Razão):</b> <p>$nome</p></div>";
          echo"<div class='col-sm-4 Dempresa'><b>Cnpj:</b> <p>$cnpj</p></div>";

      echo"</header>";     

        break;  
        }  

          //RECURSO DESESPERADO02 kk
          $arquivo = $arquivo;

//RODANDO TODOS OS ENDEREÇOS DOS ARQUIVOS
for($i = 0; $i < count($arquivo);$i++ ){

        $totArquivos +=count($arquivo); //Total dos arquivos Carregados  

    //Entra dentro do NODE "ide"
foreach( $arquivo as $arquivo[$i]){        

          //Carregando o XML
        $xml ->load($arquivo[$i]) or die(" ");
          //Entra dentro do NÓ pai do XML
        $arquivo[$i] = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );

  //Pega Data de Emissão da NF
      $chaveS = $xml->getElementsByTagName("infNFe");
      $chave =  $chaveS->item(0)->getAttribute("Id");
  //Pega Data de Emissão da NF                            
      $dataEMS = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "dhEmi" );
      $dataEmi = $dataEMS->item(0)->nodeValue;
  //Pega CFOP                           
      $cfopS = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "CFOP" );
      $cfop = $cfopS->item(0)->nodeValue;
  //Pega Modelo                                    
      $modeloS= $xml->getElementsByTagName( "mod" );
      $modelo = $modeloS->item(0)->nodeValue;
//Mostra Tabela na Tela
      echo "<table  class='table table-striped  table-bordered table-hover table-sm'>";          
              echo"<thead class='thead-light'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<th scope='row'>CHAVE DE ACESSO</th>" ;
                  echo "<th class='text-center meu'>Data Emissão</th>" ;
                  echo "<th class='text-center'>CFOP</th>" ;
                  echo "<th>Valor</th>" ;
                  echo "<th>Modelo</th>" ;
                  echo "<th>Status</th>" ;
                echo "</tr>";
          echo'</thead>';


          echo"<tr>";
              echo"<td>$chave</td>";
              echo"<td class='text-center'>".date('d/m/y',strtotime($dataEmi))."</td>";//formato de data brasileiro
              echo"<td class='text-center'>$cfop</td>";
              echo"<td>".number_format($vaPag, 2)."</td>";//Formato moeda com 2 casas(Americano)
              echo"<td  class='text-center'><b>$modelo<b> </td>";
              echo"<td>$motivo </td>";                  
          echo"</tr>";     

      echo "</table>";
```

[image: TABELA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é fazer com que a tabela encapsule o `for`, pois assim fica possível a apresentação única do cabeçalho e faculta aos iteradores a função de construir o corpo da tabela.

```
  //O inicio da tabela e cabeçalho ficam de fora dos laços for e foreach
  echo "<table  class='table table-striped  table-bordered table-hover table-sm'>";          
            echo"<thead class='thead-light'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<th scope='row'>CHAVE DE ACESSO</th>" ;
                  echo "<th class='text-center meu'>Data Emissão</th>" ;
                  echo "<th class='text-center'>CFOP</th>" ;
                  echo "<th>Valor</th>" ;
                  echo "<th>Modelo</th>" ;
                  echo "<th>Status</th>" ;
                echo "</tr>";
          echo'</thead>';

          echo"<tbody>"; //Adicionei a declaração do corpo da tabela

//Mantive o mesmo código em php só removi os espaços e os comentário 
for($i = 0; $i < count($arquivo);$i++ ){
     $totArquivos +=count($arquivo);  
     foreach( $arquivo as $arquivo[$i]){        
        $xml ->load($arquivo[$i]) or die(" ");              
        $arquivo[$i] = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );
        $chaveS = $xml->getElementsByTagName("infNFe");
        $chave =  $chaveS->item(0)->getAttribute("Id");
        $dataEMS = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "dhEmi" );
        $dataEmi = $dataEMS->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $cfopS = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "CFOP" );
        $cfop = $cfopS->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $modeloS= $xml->getElementsByTagName( "mod" );
        $modelo = $modeloS->item(0)->nodeValue;

          //Essa parte do código é exclusiva para construção das linhas da tabela

            echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td>$chave</td>";
                echo"<td class='text-center'>".date('d/m/y',strtotime($dataEmi))."</td>";
                echo"<td class='text-center'>$cfop</td>";
                echo"<td>".number_format($vaPag, 2)."</td>";
                echo"<td  class='text-center'><b>$modelo<b> </td>";
                echo"<td>$motivo </td>";                  
            echo"</tr>";    

     } //Encerra o bloco do foreach
  } //Encerra o bloco do for

         echo"</tbody>"; //Fecha corpo da tabela

  echo "</table>"; //Conclui a declaração da tabela
```

Para fazer o encapsulamento eu praticamente mantive o seu código apenas o reestruturei e removi os comentários e os espaços ente as linhas isso para tirar o foco do código PHP e destacar o objetivo que é a estrutura da tabela por fora dos iteradores.

Retirei de dentro do `foreach` a declaração da tabela, tag de abertura `<table>` eu coloquei antes do `for` e a tag de fechamento `</table>` coloquei após o `for`. Também tirei o cabeçalho e agrupei junto da tag de abertura da tabela.

Coloquei, por conta, a tag `<tbody>`.

Dentro do `foreach` deixei apenas as tags responsáveis por gerar as linhas da tabela.

E aqui o código da pergunta com a modificação:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );

//Instanciando o OBJ
$xml = new DOMdocument();

//Pegando o TMP do FORM
$arquivo = $_FILES['entXML']['tmp_name'];

    //Total de todos os XML
      $totArquivos = 0;

      $arquivos = $arquivo;

//Navegando no Nodes(Nós)
foreach( $arquivos as$arquivos){

 //Carregando o XML
 $xml ->load($arquivos) or die(" ");
  //Entra dentro do NÓ pai do XML
  $arquivos = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );

    //Pega Nome
      $nomes = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "xNome" );
      $nome = $nomes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    //Pega CNPJ
      $cnpjS = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "CNPJ" );
      $cnpj = $cnpjS->item(0)->nodeValue;

    //Mostra dados do Emitente
      echo"<header class='text-center'>";
          echo"<div class='col-sm-6 Dempresa'><b>Empresa(Razão):</b> <p>$nome</p></div>";
          echo"<div class='col-sm-4 Dempresa'><b>Cnpj:</b> <p>$cnpj</p></div>";

      echo"</header>";     

        break;  
        }  

          //Não entendi o porque dessa redundância???
          $arquivo = $arquivo;

  //O inicio da tabela e cabeçalho ficam de fora dos laços for e foreach
  echo "<table  class='table table-striped  table-bordered table-hover table-sm'>";          
            echo"<thead class='thead-light'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<th scope='row'>CHAVE DE ACESSO</th>" ;
                  echo "<th class='text-center meu'>Data Emissão</th>" ;
                  echo "<th class='text-center'>CFOP</th>" ;
                  echo "<th>Valor</th>" ;
                  echo "<th>Modelo</th>" ;
                  echo "<th>Status</th>" ;
                echo "</tr>";
          echo'</thead>';

          echo"<tbody>"; //Adicionei a declaração do corpo da tabela

//Fragmento modificado
for($i = 0; $i < count($arquivo);$i++ ){
     $totArquivos +=count($arquivo);  
     foreach( $arquivo as $arquivo[$i]){        
        $xml ->load($arquivo[$i]) or die(" ");              
        $arquivo[$i] = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );
        $chaveS = $xml->getElementsByTagName("infNFe");
        $chave =  $chaveS->item(0)->getAttribute("Id");
        $dataEMS = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "dhEmi" );
        $dataEmi = $dataEMS->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $cfopS = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "CFOP" );
        $cfop = $cfopS->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $modeloS= $xml->getElementsByTagName( "mod" );
        $modelo = $modeloS->item(0)->nodeValue;

          //Essa parte do código é exclusiva para construção das linhas da tabela

            echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td>$chave</td>";
                echo"<td class='text-center'>".date('d/m/y',strtotime($dataEmi))."</td>";
                echo"<td class='text-center'>$cfop</td>";
                echo"<td>".number_format($vaPag, 2)."</td>";
                echo"<td  class='text-center'><b>$modelo<b> </td>";
                echo"<td>$motivo </td>";                  
            echo"</tr>";    

     } //Encerra o bloco do foreach
  } //Encerra o bloco do for

         echo"</tbody>"; //Fecha corpo da tabela

  echo "</table>"; //Conclui a declaração da tabela
?>
```

Comment: Bom Dia Sr: Augusto Vasques caraca pegando a sua logica de explicação ficou facil entender, Obrigado funcionou perfeitamente aqui. Deus Abençoe, Abraço vou le seguir nas redes sociais kkk

Comment: Quase não mais uso rede social. Depois que o Facebook baniu minhas paginas eu me decepcionei. Eu tenho uma conta no tweeter mas não a uso.

Comment: Bom Dia Certo Procurei la o Face realmente não encontrei tbm n uso tweeter, mas de todo modo Obrigado --> Linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/in/gabriel-santos-498

Comment: Augusto Boa Noite, Pode me ajudar com essa questão já tentei de todo jeito aqui e nada....https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401608/pular-uma-itera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-foreach-quando-encontrado-erro-no-arquivo-php