# Pular uma iteração com ForEach quando encontrado erro no arquivo (PHP)

Tags: php

Estou trabalhando em um sistema web que faz leitura de arquivos XML em localhost, a leitura e verificações estou conseguindo desenrolar tranquilo, só tem um probleminha alguns arquivos vem com erro, porque o XML quando gerado acaba sendo montado vazio, eu não estou conseguindo fazer meu Loop ForEach pular esse tipo de arquivo e partir para o próximo, tipo assim esse arquivo com erro, o Node Pai não e encontrado e com isso o sistema para o ForEach, andei pesquisando sobre o CONTINUE mas não tive sucesso.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
//Instanciando o OBJ
$xml = new DOMdocument();


//Pegando o TMP do FORM
$arquivo = $_FILES['entXML']['tmp_name'];

//Entra dentro do NÓ pai do XML
$arquivo[$i] = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arquivo); $i++) {
    $totArquivos +=count($arquivo);

    foreach( $arquivo as $arquivo[$i]) {//Inicia o Loop pela Variavel que recebe os arquivos. 


     $xml->load($arquivo[$i]) or die(" ");//Carregando o XML 

     $arquivo[$i] = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );//Entra na TAG Pai do XML

    if(empty($arquivo[$i]) ){ continue 1; }//Aqui eu verifico se e vazio, mas ele não ta pulando a iteração, o log de erro acusa o arquivo como Vazio(Empty-File)


    }
}
```

IMg do arquivo com erro e arquivo sem erro quando aberto no navegador

Comment: Bom, o `continue` tem tudo para ser a solução que você procura. Poderia elaborar um [mcve] demonstrando o que tentou fazer e qual foi a saída obtida?

Comment: for($i = 0; $i < count($arquivo);$i++ ){
              $totArquivos +=count($arquivo);          
   foreach( $arquivo as $arquivo[$i]){
        //Carregando o XML
           $xml ->load($arquivo[$i]) or die(" ");            
 $arquivo[$i] = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );                     
                   
if(empty($arquivo[$i]) ){

                        continue 1;
                        
                      }

Comment: A tag pai e "nfeProc" estou associando a uma variavel e depois como ta ai na ultima linha verifico se vazia, logo apos uso o (continue 1) para passar uma iteração. e seguir no proximo XML.

Comment: Gabriel, você pode [edit] a pergunta para adicionar isso e lembre-se de formatar corretamente o código para facilitar a leitura.

Comment: O que seria essa linha, `foreach( $arquivo as $arquivo[$i])`?

Comment: O problema e o total de caracteres permitidos, por isso nem a formatação pude fazer adequadamente...

Comment: Essa e aonde eu rodo todos os arquivos XML que  estão na variavel arquivo, arquivos esses vindos de um form antes do ForEach eu rodo um FOR na varivel arquivo para percorrer todos os arquivos.

Comment: So encontro a minha pergunta sempre que venho aqui .. kkkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esteja ocorrendo na linha:

```
$arquivo[$i] = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );//Entra na TAG Pai do XML
```

A finalidade do método  [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName( string $name ) : DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) é vasculhar uma arvore XML e retornar com uma lista [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnodelist.php) cujo os elementos, no nível local, são objetos da classe [`DOMNode`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnode.php) cujo a propriedade [`DOMNode::nodeName`] seja igual ao parâmetro `$name`. Ou de forma coloquial ele varre a arvore XML no escopo mais elevado e retorna os elementos cujos as tags sejam `$name`.
 Esse método não encontrando nenhuma correspondência retorna um objeto [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnodelist.php) vazio.
Isso implicando que a preposição `empty($arquivo[$i])` na linha...

```
if(empty($arquivo[$i]) ){ continue 1; }
```

...sempre será falsa e nunca chegando ao código do `continue`.

Para verificar se  `getElementsByTagName` não encontrou nenhuma tag deve ser testada a propriedade [`DOMNodeList::length`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnodelist.php#domnodelist.props.length) que retorna a quantidade de nós na lista.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arquivo); $i++) {
    $totArquivos +=count($arquivo);

    foreach( $arquivo as $arquivo[$i]) {//Inicia o Loop pela Variavel que recebe os arquivos. 


       $xml->load($arquivo[$i]) or die(" ");//Carregando o XML 

       $arquivo[$i] = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );//Entra na TAG Pai do XML

       // Verifica se a lista retornada por $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" ) é ou não vazia
       if ($arquivo[$i]->length==0) { 
          continue 1; // Se a lista for vazia length==0
       } 


    }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Augusto você manja muito..